# date picker start date & end date query

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have 2 date picker (means apply 2 times), if i selected particular date from first date picker (i.e start date) then 2nd date picker will disable all those date which are less than start date.

```js
//Date picker
$('.datepicker').datepicker({

  format: "yyyy/mm/dd",

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">

  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
    From: <input type="text" name="reg_start_date" class="datepicker" size="15" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
    To: <input type="text" name="reg_end_date" class="datepicker" size="15" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Updated:

```
   <script>
<?= $this->Html->script(array('https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js','https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js','bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js','https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/raphael/2.1.0/raphael-min.js','plugins/select2/select2.full.min.js','plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.js','plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.date.extensions.js','plugins/input-mask/jquery.inputmask.extensions.js','plugins/daterangepicker/moment.js','https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js', 'plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js', 'plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js', 'plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js','plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js','plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js','plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js','plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js', 'plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js','dist/js/app.min.js','dist/js/demo.js','plugins/bootstrap-wysihtml5/bootstrap3-wysihtml5.all.js')); ?>


      $(function () {
       $('.second').datepicker({
            format: "yy/mm/dd" 
        });

        $('.first').datepicker({
          format: "yy/mm/dd",
          onSelect: function(date) {
            alert('124');
            var date1 = $('.first').datepicker('getDate');
            var date = new Date(Date.parse(date1));
            date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            var newDate = date.toDateString();
            newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));
            $('.second').datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);
          }
        });

      });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra class on 1st and 2nd text box and give `minDate` to second text box when first text box is select using `onSelect`.

```js
$('.second').datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd" 
});

$(".first").datepicker({
  dateFormat: "yy/mm/dd",
  onSelect: function(date) {
    var date1 = $('.first').datepicker('getDate');
    var date = new Date(Date.parse(date1));
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    var newDate = date.toDateString();
    newDate = new Date(Date.parse(newDate));
    $('.second').datepicker("option", "minDate", newDate);
  }
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">

  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
    From: <input type="text" name="reg_start_date" class="datepicker first" size="15" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
    To: <input type="text" name="reg_end_date" class="datepicker second" size="15" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Run snippet you can see it's working. Code have no problem. May be other js code give some error.Any error in console?

Comment: So many plugins and seems to be conflict between bootstrap and jquery ui.    Try to search `noConflict()` and how to  implement them. Also one point for check remove all plugins  beside jquery and jquery ui and check otherwise every thing looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a listener on reg_start_date. If the content changes, the datepicker for
reg_end_date must be set with

```
$("#reg_end_date").datepicker({ minDate: new Date(/*date from reg_start_date*/) });
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add a listener to the first datepicker (start) that updated the `minDate` of the second one (end) on every change

Something like this:

```js
var $start = $('[name="reg_start_date"]');
var $end = $('[name="reg_end_date"]');

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  format: 'yyyy/mm/dd'
});

$start.datepicker('option', 'onClose', function(date) {
  $end.datepicker('option', 'minDate', date);
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-12">

  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
    From: <input type="text" name="reg_start_date" class="datepicker" size="15" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 pull-left">
    To: <input type="text" name="reg_end_date" class="datepicker" size="15" />
  </div>
</div>
```